# What is meant by "proportional" and "smearing" in batterystats

Tags: adb, battery, battery-history, dumpsys

I want to analyze battery consumption of an app and ran:

```
> adb shell dumpsys batterystats > dump.txt
```

Within the filedump I found the section I am interested in:

```
  Estimated power use (mAh):
    Capacity: 3020, Typical: 3100, Computed drain: 1395, actual drain: 1510-1570
    Screen: 770 Excluded from smearing
    Uid u0a387: 364 ( wake=5.23 radio=0.0425 wifi=4.51 gps=349 sensor=4.88 ) Including smearing: 402 ( proportional=38.6 )
    Cell standby: 128 ( radio=128 ) Excluded from smearing
    Unaccounted: 115 ( ) Including smearing: 0 ( ) Excluded from smearing
    Uid u0a382: 40.6 ( wake=5.00 radio=1.40 wifi=34.2 ) Including smearing: 801 ( screen=684 proportional=76.9 )
    Idle: 27.4 Excluded from smearing
    Uid u0a83: 17.7 ( wake=0.240 radio=0.202 wifi=5.84 gps=2.33 sensor=9.06 ) Including smearing: 19.6 ( proportional=1.88 )
    Wifi: 10.0 ( wifi=10.0 ) Including smearing: 11.1 ( proportional=1.07 )
    ...
```

Each line contains info on "smearing", and if smearing is included part of this seems to be something called "proportional". These terms are not explained at all in the documentation.

Comment: Looks like [the source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/proto/android/os/batterystats.proto;l=363;drc=574b4199a111c7d6e370c8e5994050360ba20711) has some descriptions about them, though I haven't been able to really understand how they work.

Comment: @AndrewT. Looks like you are right, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Andrew.T for pointing out the [source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/proto/android/os/batterystats.proto;l=363;drc=574b4199a111c7d6e370c8e5994050360ba20711):

- Smearing: Battery consumption which is shared with other components/processes is spread among apps. IFAIU there are two categories: "screen" and "proportional":

  - Screen: Smeared power from screen usage. Screen usage power is split and smeared among apps, based on activity time.
  - Proportional: Smeared power using proportional method. Power usage from hidden sippers is smeared to all apps proportionally (except for screen usage).

A "[hidden sipper](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/os/BatteryStatsHelper.java;drc=e6eae18e2c168e2be7c16240ee0ce3ad38c27b1f;l=592)" is a source of battery usage which is one of IDLE, CELL, SCREEN, AMBIENT_DISPLAY, UNACCOUNTED, OVERCOUNTED or if it is a service or system app.

Proportional is then computed according to the [following](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/os/BatteryStatsHelper.java;l=436;drc=e6eae18e2c168e2be7c16240ee0ce3ad38c27b1f):

proportional power = hidden power * app power ratio

where "hidden power" is the power usage by hidden components(sippers), app power ratio the estimated power usage of a non-hidden sipper compared to the overall non-hidden sipper power usage.